# No device supported for my app on Google Play Developer Console

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-developers-console

I'm having trouble with the `Google Play` store that insists that my app is supported by 0 devices.
I've tested my app on different devices and it works very well, there's no reason for it to be incompatible with every single `Android` device.
Thanks in advance
This is my `manifest` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        package="com.company.nameapp">

        <!-- PERMISSION TO USE CAMERA -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
      <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

        <!-- ACTIVITY -->
        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon_flash"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            tools:replace="android:theme">

            <!-- SPLASH SCREEN -->


            <activity
                android:name=".SplashScreen"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>



            <!-- MAIN ACTIVITY-->
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">

                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <!-- CAMERA -->

            <activity android:name="com.desmond.squarecamera.CameraActivity" />

            <activity android:name=".credits"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
            </activity>

        </application>
    </manifest>
```

The 4 features being

```
android.hardware.CAMERA
android.hardware.CAMERA2
android.hardware.FAKETOUCH
android.hardware.PORTRAIT
```

And 3 permissions

```
android.permission.CAMERA
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

[Google Play Resume](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yf5OF.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml I'm pretty sure `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" />` is not really a thing. Try changing it to `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />` or remove it.

Comment: All perfect. It works!
I really appreciate your help!!!
Thank you so much!

Comment: I hate saying this, but: if it helped, please vote up or accept. ;)